# should + to be form …

Tags: grammar

At times I come across at this form of using should:

> **Should** we wish to cancel these semantic actions—sometimes termed the default actions—of
>   the event, we simply return the value false from the event handler.

It always starts with ‘should’. I understand it as ‘If we want to…’. I couldn’t find definition in my grammar book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct...this use is called "[subjunctive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood)".

Comment: OK, I get it! ‘With **should**, the speaker fells that the possibility is smaller’. Thank you, Chris!

Comment: Well, it's more just a matter that the speaker is speaking speculatively - about something that hasn't (or hadn't) happened, but might.